# EntityFramework: How to configure Cascade-Delete to nullify Foreign Keys

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

EntityFramework's documentation states that the following behavior is possible:

> If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable, Code First does
>   not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when the principal is
>   deleted the foreign key will be set to null.

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj591620)

However, I cannot achieve such a behavior.

I have the following Entities defined with code-first:

```
public class TestMaster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<TestChild> Children { get; set; }       
}

public class TestChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual TestMaster Master { get; set; }
    public int? MasterId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Fluent API mapping configuration:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestMaster>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Children)
                    .WithOptional(p => p.Master).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TestChild>()
                    .HasOptional(e => e.Master)
                    .WithMany(e => e.Children)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MasterId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Foreign Key is nullable, navigation property is mapped as Optional, so I expect the cascade delete to work as described as MSDN - i.e. to nullify MasterID's of all children and then delete the Master object.

But when I actually try to delete, I get the FK violation error:

```
 using (var dbContext = new TestContext())
        {
            var master = dbContext.Set<TestMaster>().Find(1);
            dbContext.Set<TestMaster>().Remove(master);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

On SaveChanges() it throws the following:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
----> System.Data.UpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.TestChilds_dbo.TestMasters_MasterId". The conflict occurred in database "SCM_Test", table "dbo.TestChilds", column 'MasterId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Am I doing something wrong or did I misunderstood what the MSDN says?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It works indeed as described but the article on MSDN misses to emphasize that **it only works if the children are loaded into the context** as well, not only the parent entity. So, instead of using `Find` (which only loads the parent) you must use eager loading with `Include` (or any other way to load the children into the context):

```
using (var dbContext = new TestContext())
{
    var master = dbContext.Set<TestMaster>().Include(m => m.Children)
        .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == 1);
    dbContext.Set<TestMaster>().Remove(master);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will delete the master from the database, set all foreign keys in the `Child` entities to `null` and write UPDATE statements for the children to the database.

Comment: the bold text saved me. Lazy loading is great but make sure the child objects are loaded before deleting...

Comment: I am trying this example. But got an error in "include". it says "can not convert lamba expression to type "string " because it is not a delegate type".... What am i missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After following @Slauma's great answer I was still getting same error as OP.

So don't be as naive as me and think that the examples below will end up with same result.

```
dbCtx.Entry(principal).State = EntityState.Deleted;
dbCtx.Dependant.Where(d => d.PrincipalId == principalId).Load();

// code above will give error and code below will work on dbCtx.SaveChanges()

dbCtx.Dependant.Where(d => d.PrincipalId == principalId).Load();
dbCtx.Entry(principal).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

First load the children into context **before** setting entity state to deleted (if you are doing it that way).