# Can I deliberately orphan child records in bulk using EF5+?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

For better or worse I have a need to delete a parent record (hard delete) and set all the children's parentid values to null.

If I were doing this in SQL it would be something like this:

```
UPDATE ChildTable SET ParentID = NULL WHERE ParentID = 1
DELETE ParentTable WHERE ID = 1
```

So, in EF they are connected... children are exposed via `myParentEntity.ChildrenEntities`

Is there a way to perform this operation in bulk in EF? The current implementation is a `foreach` over the collection and calling the update on each one, which results in awful SQL actions.

Comment: EF is not meant as a direct replacement for SQL.  It is designed to make it easy to work with individual records.  As such, it will issue individual commands for each record.  EF is not the correct tool for bulk actions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226312/entityframewok-how-to-configure-cascade-delete-to-nullify-foreign-keys.  However, this will issue individual updates to the child records.

Comment: @cadrell0 that isn't necessarily accurate. EF can issue bulk commands, I just don't know abou this specific case.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an example where EF is issuing a bulk commend and not individual inserts, updates, or deletes.

Comment: @cadrell0 on further investigation I was misremembering what linq-to-sql gives me versus EF. So I have no examples, you may be right. Convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is not meant as a direct replacement for SQL. It is designed to make it easy to work with individual records. As such, it will issue individual commands for each record. EF is not the correct tool for bulk actions.

EF will automatically set the ParentId property to null, so long as you have loaded all of the children into memory.  However, this method will still issue individual updates.  See [EntityFramewok: How to configure Cascade-Delete to nullify Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226312/entityframewok-how-to-configure-cascade-delete-to-nullify-foreign-keys) for details