# Does Entity Framework support when deleted a record and set the foreign key to null?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Account Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and I add the following configuration:

```
    this.HasOptional(item => item.Parent)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(item => item.ParentId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

and then I got following error message:

> Assembly Initialization method
>   UnitTest.Biz.Accounting.TestInitializer.Init threw exception.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.acct_Account_dbo.acct_Account_ParentId' on table
>   'acct_Account' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint.

I had read the documents of the EF, but I don't understand where is wrong in my code...

> If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable, Code First does
>   not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when the principal is
>   deleted the foreign key will be set to null
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete

Comment: have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226312/entityframewok-how-to-configure-cascade-delete-to-nullify-foreign-keys) ?

Comment: I thought it was supported by database side. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Self Referencing Table**

SQL server doesn't allow self referencing table to have cascading delete.

> As you can see, SQL Server noticed that your cascade operation is
>   cyclic, and it does not allow this type of cascading. This is true not
>   only for a self-referencing table, but also for any chain of
>   relationships between tables in which the cascading operations have a
>   potential to be cyclical.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

That's why in EF you can't set cascading delete on self referencing entity.

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // Not allowed.
```

**If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable, Code First does
not set cascade delete on the relationship**

is about the [default convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) of EF which you can override by fluent api. If you have following code,

```
public int? ParentId { get; set; } // <--- nullable
public Account Parent { get; set; }
```

EF will mark the cascading delete as false by default, even if you don't configure it with `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`, which actually means that the foreign key cascading delete in the database will be set as `ON DELETE NO ACTION`.

And currently EF doesn't support `ON DELETE SET NULL` unless you have custom query to drop and re-add the constraint, check [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3669916-5fbe-4e8b-8405-fa4c7ed04ffc/where-is-willnullondelete-or-willdefaultondelete?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

**and when the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to null.**

This has been explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226312/entityframewok-how-to-configure-cascade-delete-to-nullify-foreign-keys) which means only if the children are loaded into the context.

Comment: Sadly, support for `On Delete Set Null` is lacking from EF and it seems to be on nobody's priority list. I do not understand why: it is basically the same thing as `On Delete Cascade` and I don't see why implementation would be difficult.

Comment: @Dabblernl, it had been suggested in [user voice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1897819-support-for-on-delete-set-null) since 2011, but I think the administrator misunderstood the request, or it might actually ask for the default behavior..

Comment: I asked the issue to be reopened.