# Nullable foreign key in Entity Framework CF not nullable

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I am trying to generate a nullable Foreign Key - so the relationship is there when loading classes but if the dependant object is deleted, it should return null. Imagine a forum post where a User object is attached to it, but if the User deletes their account then I want the forum post to still exist in the DB and to return null for the User.

My fluent is as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbForumPost>()
                .HasOptional(b => b.User)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.UserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and my EF object class is as follows

```
[Table("ForumPost")]
    public class DbForumPost     {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual DbUser User { get; set; }

        // rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Now from everything I've read, declaring the UserId field as int? and mapping in Fluent as "HasOptional", this should give me a single Database column "UserId" with a foreign key relationship to the User table, but the UserId column should be nullable. However when examining the schema in SQL query manager, the column is not in fact nullable and I get an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Entity Framework support when deleted a record and set the foreign key to null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056031/does-entity-framework-support-when-deleted-a-record-and-set-the-foreign-key-to-n)

Comment: currently EF doesn't support `on delete set null`, when you set `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` that means `on delete no action` in the database

Comment: The error is that a foreign key relationship that is not nullable cannot be removed. If I commit the changes just before the deletion of the User object, then go to SQL and try to delete the User object in the database, it fails because of the foreign key relationship in ForumPost table is not nullable when I want it to be nullable

Comment: Does that mean I need to set on cascade delete to true?

Comment: you either need to load all the `Posts` for related user into the context just before deleting the user, or update in the database manually or using migration to change the foreign key into `on delete set null`, another option would be deleting a user will also deletes all posts `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`